# Trying to remove 2 substrings from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to find a regular expression that will remove 2 substrings out of a given string under the following conditions:

1. The first substring is always -m
2. The second substring will follow up and will end with space

For example, in this string -

```
bla blaaa ballla -m /gkdfs/dfsd/sdf bllaggw
```

The expected result should be

```
bla blaaa ballla bllaggw
```

I tried the following regex - -m (.*)

But it selects all the string after -m and doesn't stop at the first space.

I will really appreciate help / ideas

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: use this: `-m \S*`

Comment: \s matches whitespace and \S matches everything else: `-m\s*\S*`

Answer (score 0):

This can suit you :

```
import re

regex = r"-m\s\S*"

test_str = "bla blaaa ballla -m /gkdfs/dfsd/sdf bllaggw"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output :

```
bla blaaa ballla bllaggw
```

Test the code [here](https://tio.run/##NU5NS8QwEL3nVzzqZVe6VtCT4NHDwu5e1IOwIGk7TYtJGjIJ2l9fJxUHZpiP9@a9sKRx9g/rOrkwx4RISkUy9INnxOrgrnx9va2USsTpk1OUddVaDUktVVsrw8GhMV/9wI1k33A/yN1qY76FybnlVGjS3@Bjzui0h9M@C3kBB@qmYUEaCT67liLmQWwEqzty5BOjXdCN2pvJmw32mEboaHK5ilnOtvyPdCdSu818jU21xr/tGvd1QZzfT2/H0/HysldqKjKF/KQgEeLkE3Z/q/26/gI)

Test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/PfD8c5/2/)